# Reading pandas from disk during concurrent process pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, concurrent.futures

I've wrote a cli tool to generate simulations and i'm hoping to generate about 10k (~10 minutes) for each cut of data I have ~200.  I have functions that do this fine in a for loop but when I converted it to `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` I realized that multiple processes can't read in the same pandas dataframe.

Here's the smallest example I could think of:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd

def example():
    # This is a static table with basic information like distributions
    df = pd.read_parquet("batch/data/mappings.pq")
    # Then there's a bunch of etl, even reading in a few other static tables
    return sum(df.shape)

def main():
    results = []
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        futr_results = [pool.submit(example) for _ in range(100)]
        done_results = concurrent.futures.as_completed(futr_results)
        for _ in futr_results: 
            results.append(next(done_results).result())

    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

Errors:

```sh
<jemalloc>: background thread creation failed (11)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Resource temporarily unavailable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "batch/testing.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "batch/testing.py", line 14, in main
    results.append(next(done_results).result())
  File "/home/a114383/miniconda3/envs/hailsims/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/home/a114383/miniconda3/envs/hailsims/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

I'm hoping there's a quick an dirty way to read these (i'm guessing without reference?), otherwise it's looking like i'll need to create all the parameters first without getting them on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things I would try:

- Pandas has [an option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) for using either PyArrow or FastParquet when reading parquet files. Try using a different one - this seems to be a bug.
- Try forcing pandas to open the file in read only mode to prevent conflicts due to the file being locked:

```py
pd.read_parquet(open("batch/data/mappings.pq", "rb"))
# Also try "r" instead of "rb", not sure if pandas expects string or binary data
```

- Try loading the file into a StringIO/BytesIO buffer, and then handing that to pandas - this avoids any interaction with the file from pandas itself:

```py
import io

# either this (binary)
data = io.BytesIO(open("batch/data/mappings.pq", "rb").read())
# or this (string)
data = io.StringIO(open("batch/data/mappings.pq", "r").read())

pd.read_parquet(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, turns out it had nothing to do with pandas.  Running `with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:` without specifying `max_workers` the machine was running out of memory.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it! @Tony In general, it's good to try minimal code examples specifically to catch issues like this (like only reading it twice instead of 100x etc)